# A game with no pure or mixed strategy equilibrium?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I'm trying to find any and all pure or mixed strategy Nash equilibria for the game

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
& L & C & R \\ \hline
T & (6,2) & (0,6) & (4,4) \\ \hline
M & (2,12) & (4,3) & (2,5) \\ \hline
B & (0,6) & (10,0) & (2,2) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

By inspection I see no pure strategy Nash equilibrium. Not having a pure Nash equilibrium is supposed to ensure that a mixed strategy Nash equilibrium must exist.

However, when I go to solve for the mixed strategies I get one set of solutions that has a negative probability and in the set of equations for the other player I get an inconsistent system.  My work is below.

If player I plays T, M, B with probabilities $p,q,1-p-q$ then for player II

$$E(L) = 2p+12q+6(1-p-q) = $$
$$E(C) = 6p+3q+0 = $$
$$E(R) = 4p+5q+2(1-p-q)$$

providing the system of equations

$$-4p+6q+6 = 6p+3q$$
$$-4p+6q+6 = 2p+3q+2$$

which simplify to

$$10p-3q=6$$
$$6p-3q=4$$

And subtracting equations you get $4p=2$ which implies $p=1/2$ but then plugging this into the first equation you find $10(1/2)-3q=6$ implies $q=-1/3$.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Yes, the condition for nash is not that the $E(L) = E(R) = E(C)$, you get a minus value, because this condition is not possible for the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake is not considering mixed strategies that involve some, but not all, of the possible moves.

Suppose the row player plays $T$ and $B$ with probabilities $p$ and $1-p$, but never plays $M$ (note that $M$ is dominated by a $1/2-1/2$ mixture of $T$ and $B$, so this is reasonable).  The expected payoffs for the column player are then $2p + 6(1-p) = 6 - 4p$ for $L$, $6p$ for $
C$, $2 p + 2$ for $R$.  With $p = 6/10$ these are $3.6, 3.6, 3.2$, so the column player will never play $R$.  Now determine probabilities for the column player playing $L$ and $C$ that make the row player's expected payoffs for $T$ and $B$ equal.

Comment: Hm.  I can understand at least guessing that, in a sense, $q=0$ as a kind of boundary solution to the constrained problem.  However, I'm not quite getting the choice $p=6/10$ which comes from setting the expectations of L and C equal--you would get $p=4/6$ by setting expectations of L and R equal.  Does this just indicate that there are multiple Nash equilibria at this boundary where $q=0$?  Also, how do I know that there aren't other boundary solutions where $p=0$?

Comment: When Robert notes that it is reasonable to consider a mix of $T$ and $B$ (but not $M$) because $M$ is strictly dominated by a mix of $T$ and $B$, he could in fact go further and say that it is _the only_ reasonable thing to do. It can be proven generically that there are no Nash equilibria (mixed or pure) in which a strictly dominated strategy is played with probability greater than zero. That is, in any NE (mixed or pure), all strategies being played must not be strictly dominated.

Comment: @Shane, Oh, I'm starting to get the idea here--thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the row player strategy $M$ is never BR and for the column player strategy $R$ is never BR. So, exclude these strategies and compute the mixed equilibrium which is $(T,M,B)=(3/5, 0, 2/5)$ and $(L,C,R)=(5/8,3/8,0)$.

Comment: I'm not seeing why the row player would never play $M$.  I see that $M$ is dominated by certain mixtures of $T$ and $B$ like, for instance, 1/2 and 1/2.  But what if player I uses some other mixture for which $M$ is not always dominated?

Comment: @Addem: Actually, it is always dominated. $P(T)=P(B)=0.5$ always dominates $M$ (for any mix of the column player)...

Comment: @Addem: Also, in a 2-player game the set of dominated strategies coincides with the set of "never BR" strategies.